# How do I use/reference this old dll?

Tags: .net, dll, com

Let me start by saying I really don't know anything about dlls.  I inherited an old MS application and I'm trying to get it running in VS2015.  I'm fairly sure I have the solution converted and everything setup right except for this one dll that's referenced in the code.  I found that I needed to create a reference to the Interop dll that was provided and set the "embed interop types" property to false.  This satisfied all the errors and I could build the project.  Now, though, when I run it, I'm getting an exception when the code attempts to instantiate the class.  I get

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {5EA33595-626F-4C08-9392
-94DE0E344D48} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

So, how do I register the dll (or its interop?) so the application can run?  I don't think I can `regsvr32` the dll - it just gives an "initialization routine failed" error.  I think I want to `regasm` the interop dll?

Comment: if you're going to downvote this, please tell me why.

Answer (score 0):

You don't register the interop dll, you register the dll the interop points to.

For example if you have `Interop.Foo.dll` the dll that needs to be registered with regsvr32 is `Foo.dll`, you need to find that dll and either install whatever program adds it or register it manually.

A important note, COM dll's are bit version specific. Check that your project is not set to AnyCPU, you should have it on only  x86 or x64 depending on what bitness the dll you are referencing is. Also, if it is a x86 dll and you are on a 64 bit system you need to use the version of regsvr32 that is located in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe`, that one is the 32 bit version on 64 bit systems. If you just type `regsvr32.exe` in any folder besides the `SysWOW64` folder it will use the 64 bit version located in the `C:\Windows\System32\` directory.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know.  So, if I run `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe Foo.dll` and I get "The module failed to load" - that's what I should be trying to resolve?

Comment: Does Foo.dll exist in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder,? You may need to do `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe "C:\Path\To\Foo.dll"` And yes, that is what you should be trying to solve. Most likely `Foo.dll` will have been registered by installing some piece of software or SDK and you should not need to register it manually. Find out where `Foo.dll` comes from and re-install that software.

Comment: Does it have to be copied there?  This was a dll that was developed in-house and isn't part of anything else.

Comment: Refresh, I updated my comment. If it is a in-house dll then you may need to manually register it. When you release your product make sure your installer registers those dlls

Comment: Ok, yes, the dll is in my working directory when I run `regsvr32`.  Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot a "module failed to load" error?  I could be missing dependencies, but I don't know what they might be. - I did try the dependency walker, but that didn't reveal anything.

Comment: My only suggestion would have been to use Dependency Walker, after that I don't have much more I could suggest without actually being there and trying to do it myself.

Comment: You could try using procmon to see what registry entries it is trying to read and what files it is trying to load.  The registry entries might give you more information on ProgIds or CLSIDs the DLL references.  The file entries might give the name of a DLL it is trying to load through LoadLibrary.